# How to update automatically view after insert

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to automatically update view (here list named `emprunts`) after insert into my database. I use Springboot, H2, JPA, Thymeleaf, ...

There is a way to do it? Or have I to refresh the page with Get request after the insert ?

Thanks a lot!

**HTML / View**

```
...
<div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionEmprunts">
   <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table">
            <thead>
                  <tr>
                       <th scope="col">Usager</th>
                       <th scope="col">Exemplaire</th>
                       <th scope="col">Date de rendu</th>
                       <th scope="col">Statut</th>
                   </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                   <th:block th:each="emprunt : ${emprunts}">
                       <tr>
                       <!--/*@thymesVar id="emprunt" type="bibliotheque.model.Emprunt"*/-->
                           <td th:text="${emprunt.getUsager().getMail()}"></td>
                           <td th:text="${emprunt.getExemplaire().getOeuvre().getTitre()}"></td>
                           <td th:text="${emprunt.getDaterendu()}"></td>
                           <td th:text="${emprunt.getStatut()}"></td>
                        </tr>
                   </th:block>
              </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> newEmprunt(HttpEntity<String> infoEmprunt) throws IOException {
    ...
    repository.save(object);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your view technology is thymeleaf then return html page instead of returning ResponseEntity(because response entity will return data in json format) and add data in model attribute.

*There is a way to do it? Or have I to refresh the page with Get request after the insert ?*

No need to refresh page just return html page from controller like below.

```
Emprunt emprunt = repository.save(object);    
model.addAttribute("emprunt", emprunt);    
return "show"; //show.html page
```

Comment: Yes I use Thymeleaf. Ok so I need to use `modelAndView.setStatus(404)`. At the end I return modelAndView and list content will be update automatically?

Comment: For that you can perform null or empty checks in thymeleaf page itself.

Comment: So display message 1 if status is 404, message 2 if status is 403 etc? And remove all relative JS?

Comment: I asked a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090660/content-not-updated-automatically-with-thymeleaf-and-statement-if-not-working. Maybe you can help me ...